# PHP emailto form not processing?

Tags: php, html

I have previously used a php form on a contact page but now doing a second one and used the same documents and just changed them however when i click submit it goes to a blank page.
I have looked through my previous page and can not find any difference in code as yet, and its driving me mad! Im not a pro by nay stretch just challenge myself to help out my wifes business.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "karly@kbwflowers.com.au";
    $email_subject = "Mothers Day Order Form";
    $arrangement = "";
    $your_name = "";
    $your_contact_number = "";
    $email_from = "";
    $mums_name = "";
        $mums_contact_number = "";
        $delivery_address = "";
        $delivery_suburb = "";
        $delivery_date = "";
        $card_message = "";
        $base = "";
        $payment_method = "";
    $total = "";

    $email_message .= "Your Name: ".clean_string($your_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Mums Name: ".clean_string($mums_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email Address: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Your Telephone: ".clean_string($your_contact_number)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Delivery Date: ".clean_string($delivery_date)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Mums Contact Number: ".clean_string($mums_contact_number)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Delivery Address: ".clean_string($delivery_address)."\n";
    $email_message .= "card_message: ".clean_string($card_message)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Delivery Suburb: ".clean_string($delivery_suburb)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Delivery Date: ".clean_string($delivery_date)."\n";
    $email_message .= "base: ".clean_string($base)."\n";
    $email_message .= "payment method: ".clean_string($payment_method)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Total: ".clean_string($total)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>



    <!-- thank you for contacting us -->

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: sorry the html is @ http://kbwflowers.com.au/MothersDayOrderFormcalc1.html

Comment: Check your PHP error log. What does it say?

Comment: i have no idea, any suggestion where I go to find it? :-)

Comment: But that php above is not printing any html, so what do you expect other than an empty page?

Comment: is $_POST['email'] set?

Comment: Try checking your website root folder — most shared hosting providers instruct PHP to write error logs to a file there, typically under the name `error_log`.

Answer (score 0):

Your html form under that url does not contain any input with the name `email`

Thus `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {` will never be true, rendering an empty page.

Try to change to

```
if(isset($_POST['email_from'])) {

  .... your code

}
else 
   echo "you haven't filled in the form properly ...";
```

Besides: `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {` will not issue any error messages on the missing index. That's what `isset` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly is that there is an error on page submission and the screen goes blank.

Assuming you have filled the form correctly and then posting.

First to get the error please put this at the top of your page:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

This will help you get the exact error and fix the problem.

Guessing the exact error, its the clean_string function that is missing from the script page. As am not able to view all of your code to confirm the exact error.